# FieldContain Text Input and CheckBox in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

In Jquery Mobile i want do a controlGroup with "radio" and text input. I only can do it with labels!

Someone can help me?

```
<legend>B&uacutesqueda de pacientes</legend>
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio-choice-1">N.H.Cl&iacutenico.</label>
<input type="text" name="NHClinico" id="Text1" placeholder="N.H.Cl&iacutenico.">
</legend>
```

I dont need the label, Only a fieldContain between a radio and text input.

Thanks for all friends.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **display:inline !important;** on the radio group.  Here is an example with normal and mini buttons in 2 LI lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/den232/5mVv8/

```
    .floatleft {
    float:left;
 }
.floatright {
    float:right;
 }
.forceinline{  /* Prevent fieldcontain from doing a BLOCK thing */
    display:inline !important;
}
.textwidth {  /* limit width of input fields */
    width:80px;
}
.closespacing { /* controls spacing between elements */
    margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.bigselect {   /* centers select with big buttons */
    padding: 0px;
    margin:2px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.biginputheight {   /* matches text input height to big buttons */
    padding-top:10px !important;
    padding-bottom:12px !important;
}
.miniinputheight { /* matches text input height to minibuttons */
    padding-top:5px !important;
    padding-bottom:5px !important;
}

<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
```

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">first LI line</li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class= 'forceinline'>
      <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="aa"  />
          <label for="radio-view-a">A1</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="bb"  />
          <label for="radio-view-b">B1</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="left" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class= 'forceinline'>
      <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini='true'>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="aa"  />
          <label for="radio-view-a">AA</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="bb"  />
          <label for="radio-view-b">BB</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="e2" class='miniinputheight'></input>
    </div>  

     <div class='floatright closespacing'>
      <div  class='floatright textwidth'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e3" class='miniinputheight'></input>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">last LI line</li>

</ul><!-- /listview -->
```